# Force an edit text to occupy the full screen within a scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `EditText` field within a `LinearLayout` which is in a scrollview. As long as the `ScrollView` is not there the `layout_weight="1.0"` lets my `EditText` to occupy the remaining screen. But as soon as I wrap the LinearLayout within a `ScrollView`, It changes the `EditText` to a single line and layout_weight doesn't work.

My complete layout file

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"     android:orientation="vertical" >        

<TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView"       
          style="@style/TitleHeaderBarText"     
          android:text="@string/announcement" />        

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 

    <LinearLayout  
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Subject:" 
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/et_subject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Announcement:" 
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_announcement"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="24sp" 
                    android:paddingRight="24dp"
                    android:text="Save" />      

       </LinearLayout>  
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't seem to understand what I  am doing wrong. Any suggestions please on how to get the EditText to occupy the rest of the screen from within the `LinearLayout` which is in a `ScrollView`.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Facing the same problem again and this is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        style="@style/TitleHeaderBarText"
        android:text="@string/login_title" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_weight_tell_us"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_light_radial_pink" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login" />

            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/username" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_username"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/password" />
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_password"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <View/>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/login"
                        android:padding="12dp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/dont_have_Q" />           
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sign_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sign_up_" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the EditText need to have the layout_weight attribute?  If you're LinearLayout's width is set to match_parent, then setting your EditText to match_parent should fill the screen since it's orientation is "vertical".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is infact what I too thought and tried before posting here. But that did not work.

Comment: Taking another look at your layout file, I see the opening <ScrollView> tag is missing.  Is this also missing in your actual layout xml?

Comment: somehow the syntax formatter here removed it but when I went to edit it it is there. But anyhow it seems to make it appear when I put a space between '<' and 'ScrollView'. Hope u can see it now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the ScrollView attribute `android:fillViewport="true"`:

```
...
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_weight_tell_us"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_light_radial_pink"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
....
```

Comment: That did work infact. Thank you. Wonder what the fillViewport tag is for.